# Debian squeeze, mdadm. Degraded RAID5 array after each reboot

Tags: debian, mdadm, raid5

**/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf**

```
 ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid5 num-devices=4 metadata=00.90 UUID=54e55d36:c3971e21:d484c166:6e86c3d7
   devices=/dev/sdb,/dev/sdc,/dev/sdd,/dev/sde
MAILADDR root
```

**mdadm -D /dev/md0**

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Thu Apr 30 23:48:58 2009
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 4395415488 (4191.79 GiB 4500.91 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1465138496 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jul  5 10:21:41 2011
          State : clean, degraded
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

           UUID : 54e55d36:c3971e21:d484c166:6e86c3d7
         Events : 0.28886

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
       3       0        0        3      removed
```

after **each** reboot array is degraded and /dev/sde is removed. I re-add /dev/sde using

`mdadm /dev/md0 -a /dev/sde`

array getting rebuilt everything seems OK.

Until the next reboot...

**EDIT**

**dmesg**

```
1.275758] ata3.00: ATA-8: ST31500341AS, CC1H, max UDMA/133
[    1.275764] ata3.00: 2930277168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    1.275793] ata4.00: ATA-8: ST31500341AS, CC1H, max UDMA/133
[    1.275799] ata4.00: 2930277168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    1.296314] ata1.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-STDVD-ROM GDR8164B, 0L06, max UDMA/33
[    1.296714] ata1.01: HPA detected: current 156299375, native 156301488
[    1.296720] ata1.01: ATA-6: ST380011A, 3.06, max UDMA/100
[    1.296725] ata1.01: 156299375 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 
[    1.303263] ata3.01: ATA-8: ST31500341AS, CC1H, max UDMA/133
[    1.303267] ata3.01: 2930277168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    1.303375] ata4.01: ATA-8: ST31500341AS, CC1H, max UDMA/133
[    1.303378] ata4.01: 2930277168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[    1.308845] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
[    1.320424] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/100
[    1.324633] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM GDR8164B 0L06 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.324914] scsi 0:0:1:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST380011A        3.06 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.359697] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.367662] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.415713] ata4.01: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.424171] ata3.01: configured for UDMA/133
[    1.424284] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST31500341AS     CC1H PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.424515] scsi 2:0:1:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST31500341AS     CC1H PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.424753] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST31500341AS     CC1H PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.424971] scsi 3:0:1:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST31500341AS     CC1H PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.447254] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 52x/52x cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.447260] Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    1.447418] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    1.448228] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] 156299375 512-byte logical blocks: (80.0 GB/74.5 GiB)
[    1.448622] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.448626] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.448656] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.448848]  sda:
[    1.449175] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 2930277168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
[    1.449246] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    1.449250] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.449281] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.449478]  sdb:
[    1.449759] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 2930277168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
[    1.449818] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[    1.449821] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.449847] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.450030]  sdd:
[    1.453309] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
[    1.453369] sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    1.453420] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    1.453476] sd 2:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[    1.453532] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[    1.454032] sd 3:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 0
[    1.465468]  sda1 sda2 <
[    1.478018] sd 3:0:1:0: [sde] 2930277168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
[    1.478399] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdc] 2930277168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.50 TB/1.36 TiB)
[    1.478609]  unknown partition table
[    1.478667] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    1.478670] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.478700]  unknown partition table
[    1.478819] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.479134] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.479149]  sdc:
[    1.479284] sd 3:0:1:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[    1.479287] sd 3:0:1:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.479317] sd 3:0:1:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.479498]  sde: sda5 >
[    1.495522] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.500601] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.500604]  unknown partition table
[    1.500852] sd 2:0:1:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.508325]  unknown partition table
[    1.509078] sd 3:0:1:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.877343] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    1.878206] xor: automatically using best checksumming function: pIII_sse
[    1.896005]    pIII_sse  :  6515.000 MB/sec
[    1.896009] xor: using function: pIII_sse (6515.000 MB/sec)
[    1.964021] raid6: int32x1    735 MB/s
[    2.032073] raid6: int32x2    753 MB/s
[    2.100050] raid6: int32x4    550 MB/s
[    2.168011] raid6: int32x8    490 MB/s
[    2.236012] raid6: mmxx1     2367 MB/s
[    2.304019] raid6: mmxx2     2598 MB/s
[    2.372010] raid6: sse1x1    1589 MB/s
[    2.440024] raid6: sse1x2    1978 MB/s
[    2.508009] raid6: sse2x1    2976 MB/s
[    2.576004] raid6: sse2x2    3575 MB/s
[    2.576006] raid6: using algorithm sse2x2 (3575 MB/s)
[    2.587036] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    2.587040] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    2.587042] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
[    2.619394] md: md0 stopped.
[    2.622452] md: bind<sdc>
[    2.624170] md: bind<sdd>
[    2.625842] md: bind<sdb>
[    2.632060] raid5: device sdb operational as raid disk 0
[    2.632065] raid5: device sdd operational as raid disk 2
[    2.632068] raid5: device sdc operational as raid disk 1
[    2.632566] raid5: allocated 4222kB for md0
[    2.632751] 0: w=1 pa=0 pr=4 m=1 a=2 r=4 op1=0 op2=0
[    2.632755] 2: w=2 pa=0 pr=4 m=1 a=2 r=4 op1=0 op2=0
[    2.632758] 1: w=3 pa=0 pr=4 m=1 a=2 r=4 op1=0 op2=0
[    2.632761] raid5: raid level 5 set md0 active with 3 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[    2.632806] RAID5 conf printout:
[    2.632808]  --- rd:4 wd:3
[    2.632811]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb
[    2.632813]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdc
[    2.632815]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd
[    2.632852] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 4500905459712
[    2.635265]  md0: unknown partition table
[    2.692382] PM: Starting manual resume from disk
[    2.692387] PM: Resume from partition 8:5
[    2.692389] PM: Checking hibernation image.
[    2.700369] PM: Error -22 checking image file
[    2.700373] PM: Resume from disk failed.
[    2.752886] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[    2.752902] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
[    4.475170] udev[370]: starting version 164
[    5.095175] input: PC Speaker as /devices/platform/pcspkr/input/input1
[    5.096407] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2
[    5.096415] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[    5.097714] ACPI: SSDT 1f5e74c0 0026C (v01  PmRef  Cpu0Ist 00003000 INTL 20040311)
[    5.100680] processor LNXCPU:00: registered as cooling_device0
[    5.101730] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3
[    5.101742] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[    5.105041] ACPI: SSDT 1f5e7980 00152 (v01  PmRef  Cpu1Ist 00003000 INTL 20040311)
[    5.107531] processor LNXCPU:01: registered as cooling_device1
[    5.264144] parport_pc 00:08: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[    5.264369] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
[    6.020497] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
[    6.021314] intel_rng: FWH not detected
[    6.113334] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    6.228124] pci 0000:00:02.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    6.228132] pci 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    6.232413] pci 0000:00:02.0: irq 27 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.232469] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    6.241459] Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting...
[    6.255289] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    6.255345] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    6.338649] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/input/input4
[    6.989723] Adding 2650684k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2650684k 
[    7.259580] EXT3 FS on sda1, internal journal
[    7.500343] loop: module loaded
[    7.537631] it87: Found IT8718F chip at 0x290, revision 5
[    7.537642] it87: in3 is VCC (+5V)
[    7.558886] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
[    7.558938] coretemp coretemp.1: Using relative temperature scale!
[    8.122878] kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
[    8.128716] EXT3 FS on md0, internal journal
[    8.128724] EXT3-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode.
[    8.898492] r8169: eth0: link up
[    8.898497] r8169: eth0: link up
[   16.029883] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   16.116193] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (7879 buckets, 31516 max)
[   16.116698] CONFIG_NF_CT_ACCT is deprecated and will be removed soon. Please use
[   16.116702] nf_conntrack.acct=1 kernel parameter, acct=1 nf_conntrack module option or
[   16.116704] sysctl net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1 to enable it.
[   19.080019] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[  169.429012] md: bind<sde>
[  169.483527] RAID5 conf printout:
[  169.483532]  --- rd:4 wd:3
[  169.483537]  disk 0, o:1, dev:sdb
[  169.483540]  disk 1, o:1, dev:sdc
[  169.483544]  disk 2, o:1, dev:sdd
[  169.483547]  disk 3, o:1, dev:sde
[  169.483622] md: recovery of RAID array md0
[  169.483625] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
[  169.483634] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for recovery.
[  169.483639] md: using 128k window, over a total of 1465138496 blocks.
```

**EDIT-2**

**mdadm --assemble -v --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde**

```
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sde is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 4.
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md0 as 2
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 3 of /dev/md0
mdadm: added /dev/sde to /dev/md0 as 4
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 3 drives (out of 4) and 1 spare.
```

Comment: Does dmesg report anything from mdadm?

Comment: i've updated the first post

Comment: So if /dev/sde is getting removed is there maybe something wrong with  that disk? What does SMART say ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a RAID-1. In my case, because of device renaming, the solution was to remove the `/dev` devices from the `ARRAY` specification and only use the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is nothing specific in the log, and providing that the array finished rebuilding before the reboot, then I suspect that the disk /dev/sde has something up with it, a good guide to look into this using SMART (if supported nby the disk) can be found at [cyberciti](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-if-harddisk-failing.html).

If you happen to have another drive floating around that you can drop that in to test the configuration.

Comment: SMART is OK, i've double checked it.

Comment: Also, i notice in dmesg that in startup 
[    2.622452] md: bind<sdc>
[    2.624170] md: bind<sdd>
[    2.625842] md: bind<sdb>

while 
[  169.429012] md: bind<sde>

Comment: Yes, i noticed the delay, that was the reason i was wondering if something was wrong with it. Is it possible for you to swap that disk out and rebuild the array with another? 

Comment: I'm afraid not. I have concluded that there is no hardware problem
Please see this output of `mdadm --assemble -v --force /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde` in the original post